# SQL find count within date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below:

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
| UserID | CaseNumber | CourseName | CourseAttended | Training_Date | Created_On |
+--------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
| 1      | 101        | X          | T              | 01/01/2020    | 01/12/2019 |
| 1      | 103        | X          | T              | 01/05/2020    | 01/12/2018 |
| 1      | 105        | X          | T              | 01/02/2020    | 03/03/2020 |
| 2      | 101        | X          | T              | 05/01/2020    | 03/01/2020 |
| 3      | 103        | X          | T              | 05/05/2020    | 01/01/2020 |
| 4      | 104        | X          | T              | 04/01/2020    | 01/08/2020 |
| 5      | 101        | X          | T              | 01/07/2020    | 01/02/2020 |
| 5      | 105        | X          | T              | 01/08/2020    | 01/12/2019 |
| 5      | 109        | X          | T              | 01/09/2020    | 01/10/2019 |
```

I want to calculate the count of CaseNumber where the training date is less than Creation Date and also count cases where the training date >creation date. The users have multiple training dates only consider the latest training date of the user. The count should be only for the cases which have been created +-3 months of training date. For example, if the creation date is 2018 and training date is 2020 it should not be counted. The cases only needs to be counted when within +-3 months of training date.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Pls also share what you have tried! Do not simply share your requirements and expect us to give you a solution from scratch!

Comment: @Shadow I created a new column which calculates the difference between the 2 date column and I was trying to select only those values which are +- 90. Actually, I have to create a dashboard in PowerBI and I'm calling an R script in that. I'm using sqldf package to get the query. I'm not getting the right results.

Comment: Pls edit the question and share the query you have tried! Also, if you are using powerbi, then do you need to set all the filters in mysql level, not in powerbi?

Comment: Do the column names you describe have anything to do with the data you have shown?

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean? Are you asking me if it's actual data, no it's dummy I created.

Comment: No need to add new column to table, use TIMESTAMPDIFF to filter out the data by date intervals

Comment: @astentx Thanks I'll try doing this.

Comment: @Shivam Sarin answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final One Shot Query

Based on your decription, I came up with the following by implementing your requirements step by step:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM
  (SELECT d.userid,
          d.caseNumber,
          d.training_Date,
          d.created_on,
          period_diff(date_format(d.training_Date, '%Y%m'), date_format(d.created_on, '%Y%m')) AS monthsDiff
   FROM DATA d
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT userId,
             max(training_date) AS lastTraining
      FROM DATA
      GROUP BY userid)ltu ON d.userid = ltu.userid
   AND d.training_Date = ltu.lastTraining) d
WHERE (monthsDiff >=0
       AND monthsDiff < 4)
  AND (monthsDiff <0
       AND monthsDiff > -4);
```

### Solution Using Views (Including Fake Data)

Here is the data:

```
create table data (userid int,
              caseNumber int,
              training_Date date,
              created_On date);
```

Insert Statements:

```
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                1   ,   101 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-12-2019','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                1   ,   103 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-12-2018','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                1   ,   105 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-02-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('03-03-2020','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                2   ,   101 ,STR_TO_DATE('05-01-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('03-01-2020','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                3   ,   103 ,STR_TO_DATE('05-05-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2020','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                4   ,   104 ,STR_TO_DATE('04-01-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-08-2020','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                5   ,   101 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-07-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-02-2020','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                5   ,   105 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-08-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-12-2019','%d-%c-%Y'));
insert into data( userid, caseNumber, training_Date, created_on) values(                                5   ,   109 ,STR_TO_DATE('01-09-2020','%d-%c-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2019','%d-%c-%Y'));
```

Get only the last training dates:

```
create View lastTrainingByUser as 
select userId, max(training_date) as lastTraining from data group by userid;
```

Get only the cases with the last training dates. Also calculate month difference between training and created.

```
create view lastTrainingDatesByUser as
select d.userid, d.caseNumber, d.training_Date, d.created_on,
period_diff(date_format(d.training_Date, '%Y%m'), date_format(d.created_on, '%Y%m')) as monthsDiff
from data d inner join lastTrainingByUser ltu
on d.userid = ltu.userid AND d.training_Date = ltu.lastTraining;
```

The query without the count

```
select d.userid, d.caseNumber, d.training_Date, d.created_on 
,d.monthsDiff
from lastTrainingDatesByUser d
where 
(monthsDiff >=0 AND monthsDiff < 4) AND
(monthsDiff <=0 AND monthsDiff > -4);
```

The query with the count:

```
select count(1)
from lastTrainingDatesByUser d
where 
(monthsDiff >=0 AND monthsDiff < 4) AND
(monthsDiff < 0 AND monthsDiff > -4);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9184b0/7

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, this sounds like a window function to get the maximum training date and then some aggregation:

```
select sum(training_date < create_date) as num_before,
       sum(training_date > create_date) as num_after       
from (select t.*,
             max(training_date) over (partition by user) as max_td
     )
where training_date = max_training_date and
      training_date >= create_date - interval 3 month and
      training_date <= create_date + interval 3 month ;
```